# Angular loadChildren with ternary operator

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

I am trying to implement lazy loading of my library conditionally, depending on which environment the app is running on. My `app.module.ts` looks like so:

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(
  [
    {
      path: 'lib1',
      loadChildren: environment.production
        ? '@main/lib1#Lib1Module' //pointing to library published to npm
        : './lib1/lib1.module#Lib1Module' // pointing to local library
    },
    { path: 'lib2', loadChildren: '@main/lib2#Lib2Module' }
  ],
  { initialNavigation: 'enabled' }
)
```

I can get the two paths to work separately, but i get the following error when trying to use the ternary operator :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '@main/lib1'
>   Error: Cannot find module '@main/lib1'

Comment: are you sure that is "@main/lib1" and not "@main/lib1.module"?

Comment: I am pointing from ‘@main/lib1’ to ‘libs/lib1/src/index.ts’ in my tsconfig file, and it works if I do not use the ternary operator :/